# Django Serilizer: Getting an ordered dictionary in embeded serializer

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I'm one serializer inside another to show information from one model, and selected fields from another in the same response.

This looks like this:

```
class SimpleRouteClientConstraintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        default_constraint = RouteDefaultConstraint.objects.get(pk=obj.route_default_constraint_id)
        return default_constraint.name

    class Meta:
        model = RouteClientConstraint
        fields = ('name', 'value')

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    # Calling first serializer here
    routeClientConstraints = SimpleRouteClientConstraintSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = (..., 'routeClientConstraints', ...)
        depth = 1
```

When running the `RouteSerilalizer`, i want a response:

```
'routeClientConstraints': [{
    'name': 'my name'
    'value': 'confused'
},
...
]
```

If i use the serializer as in the code above, I get

```
'routeClientConstraints': [
    OrderedDict([
        ('name', 'Minimum life boats'),
        ('value', '6')
    ])
]
```

I tried changing the serializer to: `routeClientConstraints = SimpleRouteClientConstraintSerializer(many=True, required=False).data`, which i expected would give me json format, but i got this:

```
'routeClientConstraints': [
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 1),
        ('value', '6'), 
        ('created_at', '2018-11-10T14:17:39.263848Z'), 
        ('updated_at', '2018-11-10T14:17:39.263861Z'), 
        ('route_default_constraint', 1), 
        ('route', 1)])
]
```

How do i return a list of dictionaries?

Comment: An `OrderedDict` is a dictionary. When it is converted to JSON it will do the right thing.

Comment: @WillKeeling do you want to write that up as an answer?  if so the points are yours

Comment: Written up - thanks @User632716!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you're seeing `OrderedDict([...])` in the debug output, an `OrderedDict` is actually a `dict`, so when converted to JSON it will produce what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using a viewset's endpoint. I was using something like this

**return Response({"message": f"{blocked_users}"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)**

so, I was able to solve it by changing the return to

**return Response({"message": blocked_users}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)**